# Attempting to view videos in Google Drive in Chrome gives an error - "blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: google-chrome, cors

Whether I've been sent links to videos within my company or am attempting to view my own videos, I can't view any videos in Google Drive in Chrome, which is my preferred browser. If it's important, I'm in a Google Workspace for my employer but permissions don't seem to be related as I can download them or watch them in other browsers (I tested FireFox) and on my iPhone (Mobile Safari), even on the same network.

The error message displayed in the video player is:

> An error occurred. Please try again later.

When I run it with the console open, I get repeated 403 and 404 errors before it fails but the final message given when I try to watch a video is:

> `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0' from origin 'https://youtube.googleapis.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://play.google.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`

System info: I'm using Chrome on a Mac recently updated to Ventura 13.6 but this predated the OS change. Chrome has been recently restarted and updated.

I've been trying off and on for months and haven't found any solutions. I was directed to [this article](https://bytesbin.com/google-drive-video-error-occurred-try-again/) on bytesbin by someone internally but the solutions didn't address my issue or I wasn't able to follow them - it's also from 2021, so at minimum the images are outdated.

It recommends three courses of action:

1. Reset DNS and add 8.8.8.8 - the images don't match my OS version and I can't remove my home network from the list. The remove option doesn't work. 8.8.8.8 is already on the list, after my home network.
2. Clear cache - Did it, no change in behavior.
3. Disable add-ons - did it the first time I was trying to solve this issue with no effect.

I found a [bug report with the same error that's been marked "Fixed" on Google's bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229013699) and the issues people are reporting sound very similar to mine - but even after being marked fixed, people are saying it's not. The main difference is that the "origin" is `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com` in the bug but origin for me is `https://youtube.googleapis.com`. I have no clue why this is only impacting Google Drive videos, though. Viewing YouTube itself isn't an issue at all.

I'm happy to add any additional details I can that might help diagnose the issue, it's just difficult for me to know what to include and I want to avoid sharing anything I shouldn't. As far as I know, none of my coworkers have issues watching the same videos, so while I understand that the replies to the issue linked in the prior paragraph indicate it's on Google's end, I'm not sure that's the case - it seems odd that other coworkers aren't experiencing similar issues unless they just all happen to be using other browsers.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the code formatting - I was stuck between inline code which wraps but doesn't look as good and a block that scrolls so you can't actually see the entire message. I went for ease of view rather than being "pretty".

Comment: 1. Does the issue occur with other browsers, e.g., Safari or Firefox? 2. If it *is* browser-dependent, and you want to keep using Chrome, try switching user agent, emulating the connection string of another browser: https://geekflare.com/change-user-agent-in-browser/

Comment: something at address `https://play.google.com` is trying to make a request to `https://youtube.googleapis.com`  - the CORS header returned by `https://youtube.googleapis.com` allows origin `http://play.google.com` but not `https://play.google.com` - this would indicate the issue is bad coding on `https://youtube.googleapis.com`

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tested in Firefox and was able to view the videos. I do want to stick with Chrome for reasons not worth getting into. I'm not sure about the user agent solution - even if it works, it's not really a reasonable option for me. I may work for SO but I'm not really that comfortable with a solution like that. Feel free to make it an answer, since answers should help all users with the same issue, but I'll likely hold out for another option. Thanks for pointing out the browser consideration!

Comment: @Catija, as you state, it's not really an answer, but an attempt to find part of the cause. The reason to try changing the user agent (there are tools to make it easier, e.g., https://www.twaino.com/outils/seo-en/user-agent-switcher-chrome-web-store-plugin/) is to further narrow the cause. If it **is** the user agent, then the issue is with Google Drive's web site, as opposed to the Chrome browser.

Comment: @Bravo does that mean there's likely nothing I can do unless Google fixes it? Is it not confusing that my other coworkers aren't experiencing the issue and that I'm not having issues viewing YouTube videos? Would I need to create a new bug report in that case, under the assumption that the different origin from the existing report is why it's still broken? Though people still seem to be struggling with the existing bug as it is.

Comment: Firstly, youtube videos are irrelevant. Secondly, I didn't realise this was an issue only with you, and that your co-workers can view the same videos without issue. What about Edge? Does that fail too? Or Firefox?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik ah, I see. So how does Firefox working just fine not already indicate it's not Drive that's the problem in a way emulating the FF user agent in Chrome does? (That's an incredibly confusing sentence so let me know if I need to try again) 

Comment: @Catija - if the same videos work on other peoples systems, I highly doubt changing the user agent will make any difference.

Comment: @Bravo good to know (re YouTube). I can set that aside. I don't have Edge, Firefox works per a prior comment response and I also edited to mention it. I didn't think to mention that it's a me only problem - I probably would have been more explicit about "no one in my company..." but I can see how that's unclear. Fortunately, my edit earlier mentioned this, so it's been clarified in the question now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't re-read the question nor did I read a lot of the comments to be honest :p

Comment: Each browser identifies itself with a user string, e.g., for current Firefox running on Windows 10, it's "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0". Some web sites modify HTML to accommodate a browser (e.g., small and simple for Android phones). If the web site does not recognize the string, it may reject the connection.

Comment: The error occurs due to a browser-server communication issue, so it's more likely that the problem is related to something affecting the client-side code, the network settings connection or your ISP. It would be best to try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled first. By default, extensions are disabled in incognito mode, but it's possible to set them to work in incognito mode, so double and triple-check that any extension is enabled. Upload one video to a personal (gmail.com) account and check if it has the same problem.

Comment: If the problem still happens in incognito mode, could you please check if you have Google Drive apps connected? A Google Drive app might be being used instead of the Google Drive built-in video player. If your personal account hasn't any Google Drive app connected, and this was the cause of the problem, it should be able to play the video.

Answer (score 3):

Allow third-party cookies. The end.

### The solution

There are two ways you can address this issue - generally allowing third party cookies or adding the site to the list of sites allowed to use third-party cookies.

#### Allow third-party cookies

- Go to Chrome Settings >
- Privacy & Security >
- Third Party Cookies >

  - For quick access, this will take you there directly - `chrome://settings/cookies`
- Change setting to one of:

  - "Allow third-party cookies"
  - "Block third-party cookies in Incognito Mode" - allows them when not in incognito. (Chrome default)

#### Allow third-party cookies on the needed site only

There are two options for this.

If you know the URL you need to add, follow the path above and scroll down to the "Customized behaviors" section. There's a subsection with the header "Allowed to use third-party cookies" which has an "Add" button:

[image: Customized behavior section on the Chrome settings/third party cookies page with a section "Allowed to use third-party cookies" A button that reads "Add" is circled with a red freehand circle.]

If you don't know the URL or don't want to figure it out, go to the page where the video won't play. The address bar should show an icon of an eye with a line through it. This is the "Blocked cookies icon" - a fact I just became aware of when researching this issue.

Clicking on the icon will show a menu explaining the feature and a list of third-party cookie URLs that are being blocked. You can manually retype the URL from here (it doesn't allow highlighting for some reason) and add it to the list or use the toggle at the bottom to set permissions temporarily.

[image: The modal described above. It shows the text "Third-party cookies blocked drive.google.com Site not working? Try temporarily allowing third-party cookies, which means less protection but site features are more likely to work" with a toggle at the bottom that's disabled.]
(click to expand)

Switching the toggle will cause the page to reload, which leads to the video playing as expected. Note, in this case, the cookie that's added to the permissions list is more broad than the blocked cookie, `drive.google.com` - it allows Google entirely (`https://[*.]google.com`) for 90 days.

I ended up just adding `drive.google.com` to my allow list so I wouldn't have to go through this process again in 90 days - at which point I probably would have forgotten this all.

Answer (score 0):

The bytesBin article mentioned, besides the three courses of action mentioned, also mentions the use of Connected Apps to play videos, but you didn't mention having or not tried them.

Connected Apps is a way to extend Google Drive. They might replace the default file preview and the default video player in the case of videos. This could be a workaround but also the cause of the problem.

On top of the video preview screen, you should see the Open with dropdown button. This button should tell you if it's using a connected app.

**Workaround**

If you are not using a connected app, a workaround that you have not tried yet is to use one. A button to add connected apps is at the bottom of the connected app. The bytesBin suggests one, but you could look at the Google Workspace Marketplace for the latest apps and check out the users' most recent ratings and comments. Choose wisely.

As soon as you complete the connected app installation process, could you try again?

**Connected App causes the problem**
Suppose you have been using a connected app. In that case, it is possible that it's causing the problem in Chrome but not in other browsers due to changes in Chrome and the Connected App developers not being able to update the app for any reason to prevent / fix this problem. One option is to remove the Connected App.

**Another workaround**

If you have installed Google Drive for Desktop, you might enable Google Drive to open files with local apps. The available local and compatible local apps will be listed on the Open with the dropdown menu.

I have tried to open a video using the options shown on my Mac Mini, which recently updated to Sonoma, but the local apps didn't work with my video. I will try to fix this later and let you know if I find out what was the issue.

Comment: The person who referred me to the article only cited the Mac OS section, which is likely why I didn't review the remainder of the options. I'm generally hesitant to use third-party tools for privacy reasons. If I can't view it natively, I'd as soon download it rather than risk giving a third-party access to it - but that's just me. For others it may be a viable option. The only things I do use are the offline Drive viewer extension and the Google Translate extension, both from Google, but I've already tried disabling them.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for your comment. I understand being reluctant to use third-party apps. I'm the same way. I will post another answer that might repeat things that I  have mentioned in the comments but I might add more details there, and will be easier to follow up if you need clarification.